# Cannot connect tot Win10 Pro x64 VM with enhanced session

Tags: hyper-v

If I use basic session, everything works fine, but when I connect in enhanced mode, login prompt is not appearing.

[image]

Guest OS: Win 10 Pro x64 Build 18990.vb_release.190921-1704
RDP services are enabled.
Event Log for `RemoteDesktopServices-RDPCoreTS/Operational` shows a error:

> 'Failed GetConnectionProperty' in CUMRDPConnection:QueryProperty at 3318 err=[80004001] (RemoteFX module)

Host OS: Win 10 Pro x64 1903 (18362.418)
Hper-V Version: 10.0.18362.1

I disabled RemoteFX in Guest OS with policies, how it is described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/627f1c9f-fa4a-47fe-9ae2-7e467d79b91d/rds-2016-remotefx-killing-connections?forum=winserverTS), but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I stumbled across [this Microsoft thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/454913/view.html) where someone said, "disabling Windows Hello on the VM did the trick for some reason."

Go to Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options. Turn off the setting for "Only allow Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts on this device (Recommended)". Then reboot the VM and enhanced sessions should work.